# Getting TypeError in Gulp when streaming multiple tasks using merge2 -npm

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am using [merge2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge2) for streaming multiple image optimization tasks.
I am using `merge2, gulp-imagemin, imagemin-pngquant, imagemin-mozjpeg, gulp-image-resize, gulp-webp`.

When I am executing the task it is working perfectly as per my requirement, but I am getting a TypeError:-  `TypeError: Cannot read property '_readableState' of undefined at pauseStreams` in the terminal. 
My code in the gulpfile is as follows:

```
gulp.task('mergeimg',function(){
 var bannerImages = [2000,1600,1200,800,533];

 var imgmin =  bannerImages.forEach(function(size){
    return gulp.src( '../html/assets/unoptimized/banners/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}')
    .pipe(imageResize({
       width: size,
       crop:true,
 }))
 .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            use: [pngquant()],
        use:[imageminMozjpeg({quality:85})],

   }))
 .pipe(rename(function(path){
    path.basename += '_'+size
}))
 .pipe(debug())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('../html/assets/temp/' ))
 });
 var imgretina =   bannerretina.forEach(function(size){
  return gulp.src( '../html/assets/unoptimized/banners/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}')
   .pipe(imageResize({
      width: size * 2,
    crop:true,
 }))
 .pipe(imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        use: [pngquant()],
       use:[imageminMozjpeg({quality:85})],
}))
  .pipe(rename(function(path){
        path.basename += '_'+size+'@2x'
    }))
  .pipe(debug())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('../html/assets/temp/' ))
  });
var webPimg = bannerImages.forEach(function(size){
   return gulp.src( '../html/assets/unoptimized/banners/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}')
   .pipe(webp())
    .pipe(rename(function(path){
        path.basename += '_'+size
}))
  .pipe(debug())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('../html/assets/temp/' ))
 });
  var mergedStream = merge( imgmin, imgretina, webPimg );
 return mergedStream;
});
```

and my error code is as follows:

```
[13:26:00] Starting 'mergeimg'...
[13:26:00] 'mergeimg' errored after 28 ms
[13:26:00] TypeError: Cannot read property '_readableState' of undefined
    at pauseStreams (E:\xamp\htdocs\damithemes\capture-kids\gulp_automation\node
_modules\merge2\index.js:98:18)
    at addStream (E:\xamp\htdocs\damithemes\capture-kids\gulp_automation\node_mo
dules\merge2\index.js:31:25)
    at merge2 (E:\xamp\htdocs\damithemes\capture-kids\gulp_automation\node_modul
es\merge2\index.js:90:30)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (E:\xamp\htdocs\damithemes\capture-kids\gulp_automation\
gulpfile.js:183:24)
    at module.exports (E:\xamp\htdocs\damithemes\capture-kids\gulp_automation\no
de_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (E:\xamp\htdocs\damithemes\capture-kids\gulp_a
utomation\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (E:\xamp\htdocs\damithemes\capture-kids\gulp_a
utomation\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (E:\xamp\htdocs\damithemes\capture-kids\gulp_auto
mation\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\Users\Da mirecle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129
:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
[13:26:01] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_533.we
bp
[13:26:01] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:01] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_2000.w
ebp
[13:26:01] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:01] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_1200.w
ebp
[13:26:01] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:01] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_800.we
bp
[13:26:01] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:01] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_1600.w
ebp
[13:26:01] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_800.jp
g
[13:26:02] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 858 B - 2%)
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_1200.j
pg
[13:26:02] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 858 B - 1.4%)
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_533@2x
.jpg
[13:26:02] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 858 B - 1.6%)
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_533.jp
g
[13:26:02] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 858 B - 3.1%)
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_1600.j
pg
[13:26:02] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 858 B - 1.1%)
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_2000@2
x.jpg
[13:26:02] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 858 B - 1.1%)
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_800@2x
.jpg
[13:26:02] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 858 B - 1.1%)
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_1200@2
x.jpg
[13:26:02] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 858 B - 1.1%)
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_2000.j
pg
[13:26:02] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 858 B - 1.1%)
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: 1 item
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: ..\html\assets\unoptimized\banners\child-with-bags_1600@2
x.jpg
[13:26:02] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 858 B - 1.1%)
[13:26:02] gulp-debug: 1 item
```

It is seen from the code that all the images are compressing and converting to webp format as I desired, but I am really locked why the error code is comming. What I guess, my **forEach** loop is not right. Hope that is not the way. I can't figure out exactly what is going wrong. Can anybody please help me to figure out. Thanks in advance.

I could have used [gulp-responsive](https://github.com/mahnunchik/gulp-responsive) for this but since I have 32bit Windows the [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) dependency is not working. In that case I have to stick in the gulp-image-resize process.

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved. Actually I was going wrong with `forEach()` instead `.map()` to be used. I got help from the `merge2` [Github issues](https://github.com/teambition/merge2/issues/21) as I raised there also.